# Como retornar um erro em C# com Json Result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

Eu estou iniciando agora com a linguagem C#, e me deparei com a seguinte tarefa em um sistema, eu devo fazer um tratamento de erro e retornar isso em Json Result, os dados retornados devem ser coletados e enviados por email... ou seja, ao gerar o erro na página deverá surgir o botão "ENVIAR RELATORIO DE ERRO" e isso será enviado para o meu email.
Portanto está dando erro na hora de retornar, alguem consegue me dizer o que está errado nesse código:

HomeController:

```
public ActionResult ErroNaoMapeado()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult ExemploErroNaoMapeado()
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception(
                                "Exemplo envolvendo o lançamento de uma exceção não mapeada.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { msg = ex.Message, erro = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }
```

Na view ErroNaoMapeado esta assim:

```
<h2>
    Ocorreu um erro não mapeado durante a execução
    da última ação...
</h2>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //debugger;
        gerandoRelatorio();
        function gerandoRelatorio() {
            $.getJSON("Home/ExemploErroNaoMapeado", function (data) {
                console.log(data);

            }).fail(function (result) {
                if (data.erro == true) {
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

E no index eu criei esse link para disparar a view:

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Exemplo envolvendo erro não mapeado",
                 "ExemploErroNaoMapeado", "Home")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você está tratando a `Exception` com o `catch` e retornando o `Json` com a mensagem de erro, não vai cair no `fail()`... Para o Jquery o seu Request obteve um sucesso (HttpStatus 200).

O que eu já fiz algumas vezes, antes de trabalhar com Web API, foi usar uma classe padrão para respostas e uma Action para onde eu redirecionava em caso de erro

Exemplo:

```
public class ResponseViewModel{
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public bool Sucesso { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
}
```

Redirecionando para o erro:

```
public ActionResult ExemploErroNaoMapeado()
{
    var response = new ResponseViewModel();
    try
    {            
        throw new Exception("Oops, ocorreu um erro");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return ErroCapturado(e);
    }
    return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public ActionResult ErroCapturado(Exception ex)
{
    var response = new ResponseViewModel
    {
        Data = ex.Data,
        Sucesso = false,
        Mensagem = ex.Message
    };

   return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Já no javascript você trata tanto o sucesso como o erro no `success` e deixa o `fail` para falhas de comunicação ou erros que realmente não foram tratados apresentando uma mensagem padrão, como: "Falha ao processar a requisição"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //debugger;
        gerandoRelatorio();
        function gerandoRelatorio() {
            $.getJSON("Home/ExemploErroNaoMapeado", function (response) {

                if(response.sucesso)
                {
                    console.log(response.data);
                }
                else
                {              
                    alert(data.mensagem);              
                }

            }).fail(function (response) { 
                //Erro genérico
                alert("Não foi possível processar a sua requisição");

            }); 
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Você poderia me mostrar como ficaria então o meu código da forma que você esta falando???Pois não compreendi muito bem e acredito que não conseguirei adaptar da forma que você exemplificou, pois meu conhecimento é muito limitado ainda!

Comment: o único problema é que o erro quando é exibido não é exibido de forma renderizada, mais sim em uma tela em branco com a mensagem de erro, eu queria que fosse exibido na tela com o layout do sistema!

Comment: Não entendi, você quer que ao fazer uma requisição ajax no caso de algum erro no servidor o usuário seja redirecionado para outra página para exibir o erro? Não seria melhor utilizar uma notificação? caso contrário não tem motivo para fazer a requisição via javascript

Comment: eu quero que seja exibido o erro em uma página, dai eu irei criar um botão que ao clicar esse relatorio de erro seja enviada para o meu email, entendeu??